# Dynamic strings to be made into hyperlinks

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, hyperlink, dynamic-data

I have a dynamic data that populates the table in my ASP.net application. In some of the data fields I have e-mail addresses. The data is an array of strings.

My question would be if there is any way to to locate those e-mail address strings in those arrays and create hyperlinks where needed.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: can you show us some of your code please of what you have tired, and what you are trying to achieve. My initial thoughts is that you would need to use a regular expression in the code behind, or razor depending on what platform you're using. If you can supply more information then we can help you

Comment: No code yet just looking for a general approach data is fetched  from SQL database and inserted into FormViews. I imagine i would need somehow to look trough these FormViews for these e-mail addresses. But really have no idea on how to approach it. What would i search for and how to create those hyperlinks?

Answer (score 4):

In C#, you can use `Regex` to find all the email addresses in as string, once found you can replace it with a link like following code.

```
    string data = "some dummy text with email pk@email.com and one more email pk2@gmail.com and another one thirdemail@domain.com plus some more text.";
    Regex emailRegex = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    MatchCollection emailMatches = emailRegex.Matches(data);
    foreach (Match emailMatch in emailMatches)
    {
      data=  data.Replace(emailMatch.Value, string.Format("<a href ='mailto:{0}'>{0}</a>", emailMatch.Value));
    }
   //Use data, now it is formatted with email
```

Now your data will look like following.

```
some dummy text with email <a href ='mailto:pk@email.com'/> and one more email <a href ='mailto:pk2@gmail.com'/> and another one <a href ='mailto:thirdemail@domain.com'/> plus some more text.
```